# Can sound be used to identify a molecule?

Tags: acoustics, material-science, physical-chemistry, nanoscience

A few notes to this:

1. Can a molecule have a particular "response" to sound? I understand
   that soundwaves arise from the synchronisation of millions of
   particles but assuming such a fine reading was possible, could its
   response be like that of how radar works?
2. If such a response was possible - then a register could be created to link sound/responseY to moleculeY?

And so, could the use of sound, in a broad sense, be used to identify molecules?

Thanks!

Comment: @EdV can you elaborate on why? Are there any references?

Comment: Because I haven't been told why not? @EdV

Comment: Useless response/10

Answer (score 2):

As you say, sound is not the response of individual molecules, but rather a vibration involving many molecules at once. The speed of sound in any given material (whether solid, liquid or gas) can be used to infer properties of the material, and thus identify the material up to a point. But I think the interesting point for your question is whether certain molecules have a characteristic response to sound, which would enable them to show up in the absorption or reflection spectrum for sound waves. For this I don't have any specific expert knowledge, but molecules do have resonances at many different frequencies, associated with the rotations and vibrations, as well as excitation of the electrons. If the sound waves were to be at such a resonant frequency, then the sound would be causing pressure variations which in turn make the molecules approach and recede from one another (in a solid or liquid) or have more or fewer collisions (in a gas) in an oscillatory manner, and this could have a slight stimulating effect on the molecules, such that their response would be enhanced at the resonance. For example, the collision cross section, which we normally take to be a constant for gas molecules in the frequency range under consideration, will in fact have a slight dependence on frequency. This means the molecules might absorb and re-emit a bit more energy from resonant sound waves than they would do at other frequencies. I expect this would be such a small effect in practice that it would not be a practical method to identify molecules, but perhaps it has been tried and other answers may provide further information.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, much appreciated :)

Comment: This is relevant, phonons are  quanta of sound https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335757537_Chasing_the_Killer_Phonon_Mode_for_the_Rational_Design_of_Low-Disorder_High-Mobility_Molecular_Semiconductors